# MailMessage removing consecutive spaces

Tags: vb.net, whitespace, smtpclient, mailmessage

I'm using an SmtpClient object to send a MailMessage from one MailAddress to another.  I'm trying to format the body of the MailMessage to look centered using a monospace font, but the consecutive spaces are always being replaced by a single space.

So:

```
With smtpMessage
  .IsBodyHtml = True
  .Body = "<body style=""font-family:monospace"">"
  .Body &= "  ************************************************************<br>"
  .Body &= "  *     This email was generated by an automated system.     *<br>"
  .Body &= "  *            Please do not reply to this email.            *<br>"
  .Body &= "  ************************************************************<br>"
  .Body &= "</body>"
End With
```

Is being received as:

```
************************************************************
* This email was generated by an automated system. *
* Please do not reply to this email. *
************************************************************
```

I've searched around but all I'm finding are topics about line breaks not displaying properly, nothing about the spaces themselves.

Comment: Try to replace spaces with `&nbsp;`

Comment: Text-align: center ... add that to your body tag where your setting the style....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces are removed not by MailMessage, but by the use of HTML.  HTML standard is to ignore extra spaces.  If you truly wish to keep the extra spaces, you should either add the "`<pre>`" tag, or use `&nbsp;`.

Comment: The <pre> tag worked perfectly for me without littering the text with &nbsp;.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, multiple spaces in code are replaced by one space. You can try `&nbsp;` to force a space to appear.

**OR** you can try composing your message as plain text (`IsHtml = false`) (and remove any HTML from message body).